# Potential energy (in lifting an object)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, potential-energy

When a man of mass $60 kg$ lifts a mass of $20 kg$ upto height of $20m$. The energy spent by him will be $mgh$. My question is should we add the masses of both the man and the object?. (Competitive examination question)

Comment: If this is a competitive examination question then perhaps you should not be asking about it in this forum particularly as you have not formulated any ideas of your own?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether the man throws the mass, without lifting his own body with it (it would have to be an inhumanly strong man, though :)), or if he walks up together with the body. In the latter case, of course, his mass has also to be lifted and taken into account when calculating the energy.

Comment: Technically, if you lift with your legs, anything above the knees is lifted with the package that you're holding.

Answer (score 0):

add both the masses mgh=80*9.8*20 joules=15680 joules since you should consider both the person and the object combined as a SYSTEM .

Comment: Since you mentioned that he lifts it, case of throwing is eliminated.@Ilja

Answer (score 0):

You have to be more clear about your question.
The potential energy generated for man and block is (20+60)gh.
The potential energy generated for man is 60gh.
The potential energy for block is 20gh.

Assumes that man doesnt throw the block up.